# when create a lot of functions in vb.net then need to show or hide all of function in 1 click

Tags: vb.net

For example some of my function here, then i need to show or hide, or grouping for each functions in one click.

Thanks for help,
Boualy Thipphavong
========^.^========

```
Private Function sqlConfirmTopup(ByVal appType As String) As String
    Dim result As String = "ERR"
    Try
        Select Case appType.ToUpper.Trim
            Case "ONLINE"
                result = "STP_CONFIRM_TOPUP"
            Case "TEST"
                result = "STP_CONFIRM_TOPUP_TEST"
            Case Else
                result = "STP_CONFIRM_TOPUP_TEST"
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        result = "STP_CONFIRM_TOPUP_TEST"
    End Try
    Return result
End Function

Private Function sqlInsertSendSMS(ByVal appType As String) As String
    Dim result As String = "ERR"
    Try
        Select Case appType.ToUpper.Trim
            Case "ONLINE"
                result = "STP_INSERT_SEND_SMS"
            Case "TEST"
                result = "STP_INSERT_SEND_SMS_TEST"
            Case Else
                result = "STP_INSERT_SEND_SMS_TEST"
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        result = "STP_INSERT_SEND_SMS_TEST"
    End Try
    Return result
End Function

Private Function sqlConfirmSendSMS(ByVal appType As String) As String
    Dim result As String = "ERR"
    Try
        Select Case appType.ToUpper.Trim
            Case "ONLINE"
                result = "STP_CONFIRM_SEND_SMS"
            Case "TEST"
                result = "STP_CONFIRM_SEND_SMS_TEST"
            Case Else
                result = "STP_CONFIRM_SEND_SMS_TEST"
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        result = "STP_CONFIRM_SEND_SMS_TEST"
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

If someone know please help thanks in advance

Comment: Press Ctrl+M and then O

Comment: If you want to be able to hide and show groups of members then add `Region` statements.